# If $f([a]) = a$ is a function from $\mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z $to $\mathbb Z$ is it well-defined?

Tags: group-theory

I know that $\mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z = \{[0],[1],[2],[3]\}$

and that $[0]$ is equal to $[4]$ but I am not sure how to know if this function is well defined. To be well defined, every input must give only one unique output.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well obviously it isn't. As you have pointed out, if it were, then $4= f([4]) = f([0]) = 0$, but $4\neq 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just combine your two statements to find that this is not well defined. In particular $[0]$ and $[4]$ are the same, as you note. However, your definition says $f([0])=0$ and $f([4])=4$. That is, you can put in two inputs that are the same ($[0]$ and $[4]$) and get two that are different ($0$ and $4$) - so this is not well defined.

Note that you *could* define a function such that $f([0])=0$ and $f([1])=1$ and $f([2])=2$ and $f([3])=3$, but then necessarily we would have $f([4])=f([0])=0$. (And this function is even sometimes useful to define - but it is defined differently than the one you have)